# Adding additional unitOptions to MeasurementFormatter in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, units-of-measurement

Is it possible to add custom unitOptions to the MeasurementFormatter in swift? I would like to be able to define ones such as .imperial and .metric

```
extension UnitEnergy {
    static let footPounds = UnitEnergy(symbol: "ft-lbs", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 1))
}

var test = Measurement<UnitEnergy>( value: 10, unit: .footPounds)
var formatter = MeasurementFormatter()

formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es")

print( formatter.unitOptions )

print( formatter.string(from: test))

formatter.unitOptions = .naturalScale
print( formatter.unitOptions )

print( formatter.string(from: test))

formatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
print( formatter.unitOptions )

print( formatter.string(from: test))
```

Output:

```
UnitOptions(rawValue: 0)
10 J
UnitOptions(rawValue: 2)
2,39 cal
UnitOptions(rawValue: 1)
10 ft-lbs
```

Comment: Even if you add more options to the enum, `MeasurementFormatter` won't know anything about the new values.

Comment: Is there then a way to override a function in a class that inherits from MeasurementFormatter that can deal with the added values?

Answer (score 0):

You could of course create your own class that would take `imperial` and `metric` unit options and call measurement formatter with a locale that behaves as you expect and desire. It's the simplest approach and works as you would expect. Using en_US and en_AU worked as I expected and wanted it to for this very purpose.

More information and a guide here: [Introduction to MeasurementFormatter](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-measurementformatter/).